# How to add Translation Middleware in Bot-Framework-Composer V 2.1.1

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I'm using v2.1.1 and when I create a new bot, the bot is set to en-us automatically. After that i have added Indonesian language from language options. I know that Indonesian Language is not supported by LUIS. So I am trying to add Translation Middleware which is available in below links.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/3514

An example of translation middleware is available here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/17.multilingual-bot

The examples shown in the above provided links are in v1.0.0 and I have noticed that there is lot difference in between V1.0.0 & V2.1.1.

Please provide any guidance on how to add Translation Middleware to startup.cs file and other places in bot-framework-composer V2.1.1